# checkbox state checked php

Tags: php, checkbox

How do I check another checkbox when I toggled an other checkbox?

My code looks like this:

```
<form method="post"><input type="checkbox" name="checkall" value = "POST" />
</form>

<?php
    foreach($records as $r){
        if(isset($_POST["checkall"]) == 'POST'){
            $chc = "checked = 'checked'";
        }
        else{
            $chc = "";
        }
    }
?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo escape($r->id); ?>" class="check" value="POST" <?php echo $chc ;?> />
</form>
```

The code doesn't work can anybody help me please.

Thanks a lot!

Job

Comment: This is such a mess of code, and doing so many things wrong. please read : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp  and http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html  in that order

Comment: One problem is that you're comparing isset($_POST["checkall"]) which will return true or false, against the string 'POST'

Comment: isset returns a boolean, which will **never** equal to a string, hence the result of `isset($_POST["checkall"]) == 'POST'` will always be **false**. You probably wanted: `isset($_POST['checkall']) && $_POST['checkall'] == 'POST')`, which will firstly check if $_POST['checkall'] is set and, if it does (if it is **truthly**) it will check if it is **equal** to 'POST'.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
   foreach($records as $r){    
                  if($_POST["checkall"] == 'POST')
                      {
                          ...
```

`isset()` function will tell you `$_POST['checkall']` is there or not and also checks it has a value in it or not.

if you want to comapare `$_POST['checkall']` with some value, you have to just compare like example above. If you want both, then use two `if` conditions like below

```
...
   foreach($records as $r)
   {    
              if(isset($_POST['checkall'])
              {
                  if($_POST["checkall"] == 'POST')
                      {
                          ...
                          ...
                      }
              }
```

That would help you. First of all, before putting up the codes, plan a structure of your page, what you have to do and what visitors have to do. WIthout plan, you will end up reaching nowhere and stuck. The code you have presented is not recommended.

If you put some more codes in your questions, we could help you to some extent.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! This wasn't my full code of course. I will check it out tomorrow.